# How to pass a nil in place of a const record?

Tags: windows, delphi, wic

I am trying to call the WIC (Windows Imaging Component) factory method `CreateEncoder`:

```
HRESULT CreateEncoder(
  [in]            REFGUID guidContainerFormat,
  [in, optional]  const GUID *pguidVendor,
  [out, retval]   IWICBitmapEncoder **ppIEncoder
);
```

The general idea would be:

```
var
   encoder: IWICBitmapEncoder;

CreateEncoder(
      GUID_ContainerFormatIco,  //The GUID for the desired container format
      nil, //No preferred codec vendor
      {out}encoder);
```

For the second parameter, i want to pass `nil`; to indicate that i have no encoder preference

But Delphi's translation of the WinCodec.pas is:

```
function CreateEncoder(const guidContainerFormat: TGuid; const pguidVendor: TGUID;
      out ppIEncoder: IWICBitmapEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

You'll notice that the second parameter, the *optional* `TGUID`, is declared as **`const`**.

## So how do i pass it nil?

How can i pass a `nil` where a `const` record is required?

I tried the naïve solution:

```
const
   NULL_GUID: TGUID = ();

factory.CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatIco, NULL_GUID, {out}encoder);
```

and while that happens to not fail, it isn't really following the correct rules. It's passing a non-NULL address, that points to a GUID that the API doesn't know about.

I tried the naïve solution:

```
factory.CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatIco, TGUID(nil), {out}encoder);
```

but that's an *Invalid typecast*.

Comment: `TGUID(nil^)` might also work

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: +1 That's usually the point when people start to look strange at you. BTDT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
const
  NULL_PGUID: PGUID = nil;
begin
  factory.CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatIco, NULL_PGUID^, {out}encoder);
end;
```

Or as Sertac suggested, the shorter and sweeter version:

```
factory.CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatIco, PGUID(nil)^, {out}encoder);
```

I did a test and David's suggestion of:

```
factory.CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatIco, TGUID(nil^), {out}encoder);
```

Also works.

Comment: or PGuid(nil)^ to save a variable

Comment: Those are much better than the `TGUID(PGUID(nil)^)` things that i was fiddling with!

Comment: Ian, your `TGUID(PGUID(nil)^)` was a good attempt! You could just omit that `TGUID` typecast since `PGUID()^` already dereferences a value of `TGUID` so that typecast was useless there. `PGUID(nil)^` can be read as that you're dereferencing a `TGUID` pointer to the `nil` pointer constant. `TGUID(nil^)` as that you're dereferencing `nil` pointer constant and that value you typecast to the `TGUID` type.